# Formula for sales volume in 'N' period

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

My report layout is linked to a stored procedure in SQL, which returns data regarding inventory from our SAP B1 system. This identifies appropriate Minimum and Maximum stock holding values.

I draw in several fields into calculated fields. A pair of parameter fields input a 'no. of periods' value (such as 6 months) and specify an item group from the list in SAP. I currently get the sum total of items invoiced out, minus the sum total of credited in all the way back to record one in the DB.

I need to be able to get a new sales total which is sum total of items invoiced out minus sum total of credits in, divided by the no. of periods value to get a new average sales value. but I simply can't think about how to go about creating the field.

How can I get the desired behavior?

Comment: do you have no of periods value in database?

Comment: Hi, no I created it in a parameter field in Crystal not the SP

Comment: In that case you can just create a formula and write the calculation save and drag it to report

Comment: I see so something like: sum{vMPCustomMinMax.QtySold} / {?@noofmonths}

Comment: Have you tried this code what was the result

Comment: I did, thanks, it gave an average it wasn't the value anticipated.
 
I think my original question wasn't accurate.. I am being asked to provide Nett sales in a period, i.e. Q2 = 01-07-16 to 30-09-16.. so I need some how to pass date parameters from the report back to where the sales less credits data is calculated, which then filter what is passed to the main report in the total value and the separate values, then calculations will meet requirement.
 
I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of doing this, but I am quite new to Crystal, has anyone got suggestions how to do this?

Comment: can you show sample report design and what is desired output... explanation is not that clear for me to understand about the issue

Comment: sure.. I will work on getting the code uploaded